# Ruby Machine Learning and NPL algorithm to detect and correct sentences

Tags: ruby, algorithm, machine-learning, nlp

I have a database with 1.000.000M records with the following information.
Sentence | Score 1 | Score 2 | Score 3 | Score 4

My question would be what Machine learning and NPL libraries would you use and how to achieve:

- Predict the success of a new string based on parameters of total score
- Suggest what is missing to the string to improve the total score

I know this is crazy difficult so I imagine I will not get any answer. But thanks to everyone for reading and trying.

Regards,

Comment: DId you get the solution?

Comment: Nah no solution yet, maybe try with Prediction IO